# How to get a closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^i}{2^i}$

Tags: summation, algorithms, closed-form

How can I get a closed form for:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^i}{2^i}$$

I have just started studying closed forms for summations and I am still lost on this matter so I would appreciate if you guys could explain that step by step or suggest me some references for me to study.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

You have $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^i}{2^i}=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\dfrac 32\right)^i$$ and (if $r\ne 1$) $$\sum_{i=1}^n r^n=\dfrac{r^{n+1}-r}{r-1}.$$ Thus ... (please, complete).

Answer (score 0):

You can write 
$\frac{a^i}{b^i}$ 
as $(\frac{a}{b})^i$

thus

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^i}{2^i}=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\dfrac 32\right)^i$$
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^i}{2^i}=\dfrac 32+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^2+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^3+\cdots+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^n$$

this is geometric series with $r=\frac{3}{2}$

$$S=\dfrac 32+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^2+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^3+\cdots+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^n$$
multiply both sides by  $\frac{3}{2}$

$$\frac{3}{2}S=\hspace{12pt}\left(\dfrac 32\right)^2+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^3+\cdots+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^n+\left(\dfrac 32\right)^{n+1}$$

subtract both equations

$$\frac{3}{2}S-S=\left(\dfrac 32\right)^{n+1}-\dfrac 32$$
$$\frac{S}{2}=\frac{3}{2}\left(\left(\dfrac 32\right)^{n}-1\right)$$
$$S=3\left(\left(\dfrac 32\right)^{n}-1\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. When you mention "subtract both equations", it seems that you are subtracting S in the left side and $\frac{3}{2}$ in the right side. Is that correct?